# Do wrapper class objects get unboxed while being assigned to another object?

Tags: java, wrapper, autoboxing

When we assign objects of the same type to one another, the new object stores the address of the object that's being assigned to it. For instance, if I have my own class named `CLA` then the following code will produce `11` as the output:

```
public class CLA{
    int val;
    public static void main(String...args){
        CLA ob1 = new CLA();
        ob1.val = 10;
        CLA ob2 = ob1;
        ob1.val++;
        System.out.printf("%d", ob2.val);
    }
}
```

because `ob2` would refer to `ob1` and consequently show `ob1`'s `val`.

However, the same doesn't happen for **Wrapper classes**. When I assign an `Integer` object to another, the operation simply behaves like we're dealing with values and not objects. As opposed to the above code, the output of the below code is `10`:

```
Integer x = 10; //auto-boxed as new Integer(10)
Integer y = x;
x++;
System.out.printf("%d", y.intValue());
```

### Why does this happen?

**Do wrapper class objects get unboxed while being assigned to another object, so as to pass the value instead of the address??**

Comment: The Java primitive wrapper types are immutable.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch But if I display **x**'s value, the output is `11`.

Comment: `x++` is equivalent to `x = Integer.valueOf(x.intValue() + 1)`. It doesn't change the state of the Integer referenced by x. It assigns another Integer to x. Wrapper classes are all immutable: their state can't change.

Comment: @JBNizet _"It does't change the state of the integer referenced by x; it assigns another integer to x."_ I didn't get it: doesn't it mean that there are two values on x???

Comment: x was a reference to a given Integer object, containing the value 10. And after `x++` is executed, x references a different Integer object, containing the value 11. I don't know how I can explain it differently. And I don't know what you mean by "there are two values on x".

Comment: It's clear to me now. I was a little confused earlier as I had hovered over the _"immutable"_ part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `x++`, it is the same as `x = x + 1` so it is actually a new instance of `Integer` assigned to x but y still points to the old instance which value is 10.

Keep in mind that wrapper instances are immutable.

Answer (score 1):

For an Integer `x`, the expression `x++` can be understood like `x = new Integer(x.intValue() + 1);`. Its not exactly the same, but helps for understanding.

So, it doesn't modify the `Integer` object with the value `10` that `x` pointed to before the `x++`, it creates a new `Integer` object with the value `11` independent of the original `10` Integer, and assigns this `11` Integer to `x`.

But there's nothing in the `x++` expression that would make `y` point to a different Integer instance. So `y` still points to the original 10.

That's the difference to the `CLA` example where you don't introduce a new instance with `ob1.val++`, but modify the single instance. If the `Integer` class had a public field `value`, then `x.value++` would show the behaviour you expected - but the `value` field is (for good reason) private - not accessible to the outside.